# OWL Carousel 2: URL Hash Navigation - Link to current slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-routing, owl-carousel

I'm using the excellent slider OWL Carousel 2. http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

My issue is the `URLhashListener` option only allows you to create a link to a specific slide but does not allow the user to copy the url link from the current slide to share. I would assume the correct behaviour of this option would be the URL updates as the user moves to the next slide so they can then copy that unique URL. 
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/urlhashnav.html

My OWL code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
    owl.owlCarousel({
      smartSpeed:1500,
      items:1,
      lazyLoad:true,
      loop:true,
      URLhashListener:true,
      startPosition: 'URLhash',
      nav: true,
    });
  });
  //]]>
</script>
```

I'm using `data-hash` in my image tag to generate the hash id for each image which works fine (you can link to the specific slide). But when you click `next` and arrive at the next slide the URL will remain as `#HASHID`. The link no longer corresponds to the current slide.

```
<img id="zm" class="owl-lazy owlimg" data-hash="slideID" data-src="myimagelink.jpg">
```

Here's a live page with the url hash nav working:
http://www.legacyart.pinkpoliceman.com/collections/birds-of-prey/

With hash:
http://www.legacyart.pinkpoliceman.com/collections/birds-of-prey/#slide14

I'm sure these docs hold part of the answer but I'm not sure how to piece it all together. http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html

Comment: http://mycode.in.ua/js/jquery/plugins/owl-carousel-sync.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update (Native solution)**

It seems that once you add `data-hash` to your items, the plugin take care about all the functionality.

http://jsbin.com/javuwod/edit?html,js

**Original Answer**

You can easily "listen" to slide changed event using [`changed.owl.carousel`](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html), then you can change the hash according the slide's index.

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  margin:10,
  nav:true,
  URLhashListener: true,
  startPosition: 'URLHash'
});
// Listen to owl events:
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  location.hash = 'slide' + event.property.value;
})
```

```html
<link href="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div id="demos">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide0">
      <h4>1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide1">
      <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide2">
      <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide3">
      <h4>4</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide4">
      <h4>5</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide5">
      <h4>6</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide6">
      <h4>7</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide7">
      <h4>8</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide8">
      <h4>9</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide9">
      <h4>10</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide10">
      <h4>11</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-hash="slide11">
      <h4>12</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/javuwod/edit?html,js

Comment: Thanks for your help, a couple of issues. It seems to break when using the option - loop: true. It jumps strangely around. I would ideally like to use the loop. Also my data-hash's start at 1 not 0 and this stops the carousel working. And finally my data-hash ids might be words or titles rather than a sequence. For example "bird", "frog", "dog". Is that possible to get the dynamic id of the data hash, rather than them being predetermined number sequences?

Comment: @pinkp Actually it seems that once you add `data-hash` to your items, the plugin take care about all the functionality. I was updated the bin. Take a look.

Comment: Wow! thank you for helping me get to the bottom of this. Turns out its my version of Owl's JS which stopped it working. I used the version you linked to and it all works as expected! Where did you get your version 2.1.6, I had 2.0.0 but this came straight from the site.